# To control the decimal point in real value AX2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

"
To control the decimal point in real value do the following :

1- right click on the real field and choose properties

2- go to NoOfDecimals property and put any number you want for example (1 or 2 or 3)

This means the numbers after the decimal point  example :

if the value is 2.31689

if you put 1 the result is 2.3

if you put 2 the result is 2.31

"
from https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/msdynamicsaxbyabdelfattahahmed/posts/how-to-control-the-decimal-point-in-real-values-in-ax

how can i do this in code for 5 ?

Comment: are you talking about rounding?

Comment: What have you tried so far?